# How can I measure memory taken by an object from external library?

Tags: python

For instance I have a pythonic object based on non-pythonic one (from external library written in Rust). Is there any way to correctly measure memory taken by this object? I know about `sys.getsizeof()` and `pympler.asizeof.asizeof()` but the first one is not suitable as it's only for default python types and the second one is questionable, I only know that it works with custom python classes.

Comment: Can you pickle the object?

Comment: To be honest, I've no idea. What can prevent from pickling the object?

Comment: Have you considered using a memory profiler? https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/

Comment: I was thinking about using such modules as memory profiler or tracemalloc but I'm not sure if they're able to trace memory allocated for non pythonic objects, python code in my case is only a wrapper that invokes rust code.

Comment: They should do the job anyway. Give it a try